# blur() and focus() not working on jQuery with replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, forms, focus, blur, replacewith

I'm working on a form with jQuery that when you click on a certain field, it will display tips on what to do in that field in a

tag. With the code I have now, it will work for the first element, but then after that if I try to click another one it will not overwrite the previous change. I tried to use empty() on blur but that won't clear anything out, and I don't know if that would really solve the problem anyway. If anybody could give me any insight with what's wrong here I would really appreciate it!

#helpP is the paragraph that I want to change text within. The other IDs are just form fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mail").focus(function() {
        $("#helpP").replaceWith("<p>This e-mail address will be used as your login and for receiving special offers from Volga</p>");
    }).blur(function(){
        $("helpP").empty();
    });

    $("#confirmEmail").focus(function() {
        $("#helpP").replaceWith("<p>Confirm your e-mail</p>");
    });

    $("#confirmEmail").blur(function() {
        $("#helpP").empty();
    });

    $("#passwordReg").focus(function() {
        $("#helpP").replaceWith("<p>Passwords can only have letters and numbers and are case sensitive.</p>");
    });

     $("#passwordRegConfirm").focus(function() {
         $("#helpP").replaceWith("<p>Enter the same password again to ensure accuracy</p>");
     });
 });
```

I tried chaining with the first one to see if that made any difference, but it does not.

Comment: have you tried to replace it with html() and not with replaceWith()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith) try to use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) like,

```
$("#mail").focus(function() {
    $("#helpP").html("<p>This e-mail address will be used as your login and for receiving special offers from Volga</p>");
}).blur(function(){
    $("#helpP").empty();// use # before id selector
});
```

From **replaceWith()** Docs,

> **Description:** Replace each element in the set of matched elements with
>   the provided new content and return the set of elements that was
>   removed.

And it your `elements` will be `replaced` with `p elements`

Comment: Awesome that works! Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked something that simple.